# Twitter Bootstrap and gmaps4rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, gmaps4rails

I have the following view code and it dynamically adjusts its size for mobile phone as well as the desktop. However the map doesn't change size. Is there a way to make it so that the map changes size dynamically to fit on the phone/tablet/desktop using bootstrap? (see below)

```
.row
  .span6.offset3
    .well
      = gmaps4rails(@maps_json)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. Changed the width and height to 100% in the gmaps4rails.css file

Comment: Great at answering your own questions :)+1

Answer (score 2):

didn't work for me, 
to fix it i changed in gmaps4rails.css:

```
.map_container {
  width: 100%;
}

.gmaps4rails_map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

And this for fix the toolbar

```
#map label { width: auto; display:inline; }
#map img { max-width: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. This fixed it for me:

```
.gmaps4rails_map img {
    max-width: none;
}
.gmaps4rails_map label {
    width: auto; display:inline;
}
```

It it doesn't fix the problem, try replacing the selector `.gmaps4rails_map img` by just `img` to make sure you need this particular css fix. Then try another map selector before img.